# Множественное подключение к websocket при рестарте nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Суть такова, есть банальный сервер websocket на nodejs

```
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        var ID = (socket.id).toString();
        console.log(socket);
        socket.on('message', function(msg) {
            socket.send(msg);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log(ID+" disconnect");
        });
    });
```

И банальный клиент

```
var socket = io.connect('https://********:8443');
socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

При рестарте nodejs на сервере, клиент переподключается (если страница была не перезагружена), но при этом остаётся и предыдущее подключение. Так при отправке сообщения socket.send({test: ''}); обратно приходит уже не одно, а n-количество сообщений.
Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var socket = io.connect('https://********:8443');
socket.once('connect', function () {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Использовать once вместо one